# How does fsockopen work in php

Tags: php, fsockopen

I am very new to socket programming. I saw a bit of code like

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

At end i see its doing a fwrite. My question is how does it execute the remote php code using fwrite.

Comment: It's doing the same thing as your browser would, a simple HTTP GET request. It's not executing the remote PHP, it's the server that is executing the PHP, and returning the outputting HTML/other.

Answer (score 2):

This code is connecting to a webserver, and sending an HTTP request, just like a browser would. The remote code executes because that's what the webserver is configured to do when you request that document.

Comment: how does     fwrite($fp, $out); execute the code. it is for writing to a file right?

Comment: It's for writing to any kind of stream. Opens a network connection to the server, and `$fp` is the stream that communicates with the server.